# Sampling unique set of records in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, query-performance

I have an Oracle table that from which I need to select a given percentage of records for each type of a given set of unique column combination.

For example,

```
SELECT distinct column1, column2, Column3 from TableX;
```

provides me all the combination of unique records from that table. I need a % of each rows from each such combination. Currently I am using the following query to accomplish this, which is lengthy and slow.

```
SELECT *  
FROM tableX Sample ( 3 ) 
WHERE Column1 = ‘value1’ and       
      Column2 = ‘value2’ and       
      Column3 = ‘value3 

UNION 

SELECT *  
FROM tableX Sample ( 3 ) 
WHERE Column1 = ‘value1’ and       
Column2 = ‘value2’ and       
Column3 = ‘value4 

UNION  
 …   
 …  
SELECT *  
FROM tableX Sample ( 3 ) 
WHERE Column1 = ‘valueP’ and       
Column2 = ‘valueQ’ and       
Column3 = ‘valueR’
```

Where the combination of suffix in the “Value” is unique for that table (obtained from the first query)

How can I improve the length of the query and speed?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column1, column2, column3 order by dbms_random()
                               ) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by column1, column2, column3) as totcnt
      from tablex t
     ) t
where seqnum / totcnt <= 0.10 -- or whatever your threshold is
```

It uses `row_number()` to assign a sequential number to rows in each group, in a random order.  The `where` clause chooses the proportion that you want.